# Nested range() in range() in Python

Tags: python, numpy

Can you nested the range in range? Use variable in range? Because I would like to get some effect. To illustrate the problem I have the following pseudocode:

```
for i in range(str(2**i) for i in range(1,2)):
    print (str(i*0.01))
```

At the exit I would like to receive:

```
0   0.01
1   0.01
2   0.02
3   0.02
4   0.02
5   0.02
```

Where the number of numbers 0.01 in the column will be 2^1, the number of numbers 0.02 are 2^2, the number of numbers 0.03 are 2^3, and so on ... I will be grateful for any hint as to how to approach this.

Comment: This raises more self-referential questions than it should :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For this specific task you'll want to nest them like this:

```
for i in range(1,3):
    for j in range(2**i):
        print(i * 0.01)
```

which will print what you want. What this is doing is taking a number `i` in `range(1,3) #[1,2]` and then print `i * 0.01` `2**i` number of times which I believe is what you are trying to do.

Comment: That's exactly what it was. Thank you very much!